# Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)' swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsession

I've tried to look at other answers with this same problem but I still can not fix this. Please help me with this code which is for a weather app. The problem is on my `let task = sessionDataTask` line.

```
import Foundation

protocol WeatherServiceDelegate {
    func setWeather(weather: Weather)
}
class WeatherService {
    var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegate?
    func getWeather(city: String)  {
        let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=79933f5c001b81aecc59976577f8134f"
        let url = NSURL(string: path)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            print(data)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use URL instead or NSURL

Comment: Also it is Swift convention to name your Protocols, Structures and Classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: In your protocol you defined setWeather but in your class you named your method getWeather with different parameter

Answer (score 2):

Change your

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)
```

to

```
let url = URL(string: path)
```

That will fix your code

Comment: As a rule of thumb for swift >2.x: remove NS everywhere (apart fro some particular case for example NSString..)ou can fall in strange errors, for example: